# Restart timer anytime button is clicked again

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button when clicked starts a timer. Problem is when the button is clicked again the timer doesn't restart, it just goes crazy fast.

```
var timeleft = 1800;
function rig() {
var Timer = setInterval(function 
   function1(){ 
document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = Math.floor(timeleft / 60) + ":" + (timeleft % 60 ? timeleft % 60 : '00') + "&nbsp"+"minutes remaining";
timeleft -= 1;
if(timeleft <= 0){
clearInterval(Timer);
document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time out"
  }
}, 1000);
    console.log(countdown)
}


<p id="countdown"></p>
<button onclick="rig();">Start Time</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable that you set whenever the timer gets started and stopped.

**Pause the time**

```js
let timeBreak = false;
var timeleft = 1800;

function rig() {
  if (!timeBreak) {
      timer = setInterval(function function1() {

      document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = Math.floor(timeleft / 60) + ":" + (timeleft % 60 ? timeleft % 60 : '00') + "&nbsp" + "minutes remaining";
      timeleft -= 1;
      if (timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time out"
      }
    }, 1000);
    timeBreak = true;
  } else {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timeBreak = false;
  } 
}
```

```html
<p id="countdown"></p>
<button onclick="rig();">Start Time</button>
```

**Reset the time**

```js
let timeBreak = false;
var timeleft = 1800;

function rig() {
  if (!timeBreak) {
    timer = setInterval(function function1() {

      document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = Math.floor(timeleft / 60) + ":" + (timeleft % 60 ? timeleft % 60 : '00') + "&nbsp" + "minutes remaining";
      timeleft -= 1;
      if (timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time out"
      }
    }, 1000);
    timeBreak = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = ''; // Remove that line if you want to see the stopped time
    clearInterval(timer);
    timeleft = 1800;
    timeBreak = false;
  } 
}
```

```html
<p id="countdown"></p>
<button onclick="rig();">Start Time</button>
```

Also ensure that you are not using `var`, `let` or `const` before `timer`, since you want to use that variable out of scope.

Comment: This doesn't reset the timer, this just pauses it. Please what i need is the timer to reset not pause. Thanks

Comment: You just need to reset `timeleft`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. What i wanted was to make the timer restart on second click. I got it working by removing the last "timeBreak = false;"